# React native app detect background apps activity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to achieve this scenario: when user opnened my app, then he play a song in Spotify, my app can get title of the song. Is it possible to build an app like that with react native?

Answer (score 0):

You can try without any library. Just using the Spotify API to capture the user current song.

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/get-the-users-currently-playing-track/

If you want to have always update in your state, try to create a listener function that in times request to this spotify API.